# Trigger postgresql en una columna específica

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Estoy manejando triggers. No encuentro cómo hacer que se ejecute el trigger cuando se actualiza una columna en específico, es decir si tengo la tabla

```
create table public.pruebas(
    pruebas_id serial4 NOT NULL,
    pruebas_campo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    prubas_estado bool DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT pkey_pruebas PRIMARY KEY (pruebas_id)
);
```

y el trigger

```
create trigger tg_enviar after
update
    on
    public.pruebas for each row execute procedure pruebas.funcion()
```

quiero que se ejecute solo cuando se actualice la columna *pruebas_estado*.

Comment: Cambiá el enfoque: ¿por qué no preguntar si el valor nuevo de esa columna es distinto del valor viejo, como para efectuar las acciones correspondientes? No hay problemas con que se dispare el trigger cada vez que se modifique cualquier columna de esa tabla: lo que marcará la diferencia es la condición que menciono.